# How do I open an application without specifying the location of the file?

Tags: c#

Process.Start(@"\dat\bind\pingudata.exe");
(Unhandled Exception) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The network path was not found'

How do I open a process without giving the specific location? I have tried using all sorts of methods with Process Start? I am aware what I am asking for is possible but there are no tutorials and I forgot how I did it before. I'm fairly new to StackOverflow.

Comment: Either use `\\server\...` if your path is really a network path, `.\dat\bind\pingudata.exe` to explicitly work relative to the current directory or just `pingudata.exe` if you really don't want to specify a location and rely on the search path. Note that `\dat\bind\pingudata.exe` is still a legal path, but works relative to the root of whatever the current drive is, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Please read [ask], [answer] and the rest of the [help]. It will answer your questions about how to do things on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I don't know how to explain this so here's my answer.

**Process.Start(@"\dat\bind\pingudata.exe");** is wrong since after '@"' it specifies the \ location. Removing the \ should fix it.

```
Before: Process.Start(@"\dat\bind\pingudata.exe");
After:  Process.Start(@"dat\bind\pingudata.exe");
```

Here you can notice the removal of the first `"\"` which fixed the error.